# Discord bot clear command

Tags: javascript, discord, autocode

I would like my bot to delete only two messages but I don't know what command I have to do for it to do that.

```
const lib = require('lib')({token: process.env.STDLIB_SECRET_TOKEN});
 
await lib.discord.channels['@0.1.1'].messages.destroy({
    message_id: `${context.params.event.message.id}`,
    channel_id: `${context.params.event.message.channel_id}`
  });
```

Comment: “*I don't know what command I have to do for it to do that.*” Have you tried researching it on your own first, in accordance with [ask]? We’re not your personal research service. The library you’re using is *very* well documented.

Comment: I don't get the issue. It looks like you know how to delete one message, so just repeat that to delete the second message?